# Adding folder in Resource folder, then adding XML file - Intellisense stops working - Xamarin Android VS 15

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Ok, I have a problem. I'm working on Xamarin Android VS 15. I added a folder called "menu" to my resources folder, and added an XML file in it. Initially, on my MainActivity, I was unable to find the Menu folder or the XML file in it. "Resource does not contain attribute 'menu'".

I went through many stackoverflow and xamarin forum threads, and followed several tips.

1)Clean and  Rebuild.
2)Delete obj and bin.
3)Check buildaction on the created file.
4)Delete Appdata/Local/Xamarin.

The fourth tip worked. I am now able to find my newly created "menu" folder and the files in it, but a new problem arose.

My intellisense has stopped working. Autocomplete of android syntax and methods is not working in either AXML or my CS files, ONLY FOR THIS SPECIFIC PROJECT. The normal green/blue color on my Xamarin/Android syntax is not appearing either. On my other projects, my intellisense works absolutely fine.

This has happened to me before as well, and I need your help to fix this. It seems, SOMETIMES, when I create new Resource folders and files, my intellisense stops working automatically.

Can anybody please tell me why this could be, and how I can fix it?

Thanks and Regards,

Aditya

Comment: Try to rebuild your app and then unload, reload your project, if still doesn't work, reopen your VS. It happens a lot with Xamarin android that intellisense stops working.

Comment: I've tried it all. Unfortunately, even the 'menu' being recognized by the compiler turned to be a blank. It is not recognizing the 'menu' resource anymore, and neither is Intellisense working. I've raised a bug on bugzilla, I hope this is fixed soon.