# Xamarin Forms Android Error: "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo...." After adding .wav file to Resource

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added a .wav file to my Resource/Raw folder and set the Build Action to AndroidResource
and use it like this

```
 _mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(global::Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.error);
```

the project compiles but crashes at runtime (startup) with the following error

`Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname.xxxx.App/md5f540acf9c8bcb717b4f7be48f65fc9d3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setAttachListener(android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener)' on a null object reference`

I use xamarin.forms version 2.5.0.122203
MonoAndroid v7.1

Answer (score 2):

I´ve had a similiar issue in the startup and got the same error. Cleaning and Rebuilding as well as Deleting the 'bin' and 'obj' file worked for me.

Check this out: [Adding folder in Resource folder, then adding XML file - Intellisense stops working - Xamarin Android VS 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467698/adding-folder-in-resource-folder-then-adding-xml-file-intellisense-stops-work)